# Checking if DropDownListFor item is selected in html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have cshtml page like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QuestionnaireName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.QuestionnaireName, Model.Questionnaires, new { @id = "ddlQuestionnaires", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.Label("Questions list:", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    // here: how to check if any dropdownlistfor value is selected?

</div>
```

Like i said in comment above. I want to check if value of DropDownListFor is selected and in case yes, build dynamicaly (table or list) for element of chosen Questionnaire.

Let say that Questionnaire.name is unique id and Questionnaire contain List Questions.

here is my model:

```
public class FillQuestionnaireModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Select questionnaire")]
    public string QuestionnaireName { get; set; }

    public SelectList Questionnaires { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller actions:

```
    public ActionResult Fill()
    {
        QuestionnaireServiceReference.QuestionnaireServiceClient client = new QuestionnaireServiceReference.QuestionnaireServiceClient();

        FillQuestionnaireModel model = new FillQuestionnaireModel();
        List<QuestionnaireServiceReference.Questionnaire> Questionnaires = client.GetAllQuestionnaires().ToList();

        Questionnaires.Insert(0, new QuestionnaireServiceReference.Questionnaire() { questionnaire_id = 0, name = "--Select--" });

        model.Questionnaires = new SelectList(Questionnaires, "name", "name");
        return View(model); 
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Fill(FillQuestionnaireModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string SelectedValue = model.QuestionnaireName;

            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            QuestionnaireServiceReference.QuestionnaireServiceClient client = new QuestionnaireServiceReference.QuestionnaireServiceClient();
            List<QuestionnaireServiceReference.Questionnaire> Questionnaires = client.GetAllQuestionnaires().ToList();

            Questionnaires.Insert(0, new QuestionnaireServiceReference.Questionnaire() { questionnaire_id = 0, name = "--Select--" });

            model.Questionnaires = new SelectList(Questionnaires, "name", "name");
        }
        return View(model);      
    }
```

Comment: $('#ddlQuestionnaires').val() should give you the value of the drop down list in HTML page.

Comment: @Dreamweaver okey but how to use it ? i tried smth like this `@if ( $('#ddlQuestionnaires').val() != null ) { }` but causes syntax error near $

Comment: Value on Html means to have the  value on client side, correct ?? if my understanding is correct then we it will be written in script tag as javascript function  if ( $('#ddlQuestionnaires').val() != null ) { }

Comment: you are correct. i will try it then

Comment: That assumes he's including jQuery.  If you're not using jQuery use this, if (document.getElementById("ddlQuestionnaires'").value != null) { }

Comment: @ScottMacMaster okey, i prefer that way. However i still dont get it how to call this statement in my htmlpage (marked as "here")

Comment: To put it there you would wrap it in a script tag.  <script>if (document.getElementById("ddlQuestionnaires'").value != null) { }</script>

Comment: Unsure what your asking. Are you wanting up update the DOM with the table based on the selected `QuestionnaireName` whenever the user selects a `QuestionnaireName` (without leaving the page)? Or are you wanting to POST and then redirect to another page that displays the table? Your controller code has numerous errors so hard to tell what your trying to do.